# carousel slider showing images in new lines one after another not in a single line(sliding images)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, carousel

I am trying to show images in carousel slider but the problem is that images are not showing in one line and sliding also not working every image is showing in new line, next and previous button also not showing. Please check code below

```
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" id="homepageItems">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="/assets/Gallery/vd33qk3l.pj0.PNG"/>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="/assets/Gallery/spzkmguq.duw.PNG"/>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="/assets/Gallery/bzmxjuy1.3ou.PNG"/>
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried "float:left"

```
<style>
.carousel-inner .item{
  float:left;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfn07tkv/